# AutoIt - writing text to the end of a line

Tags: autoit, append

I'm working with AutoIt, and I was wondering in there is a method I can use to append a string of text to the end of a line inside a text file. I've been browsing all over autoIt forums and there are lots of answers that are really close, but I have not found a solution that has actually worked for me. A few I didn't even really understand but tried anyway, with no luck.

The function:

```
FileWriteLine($LOG, "FText")
```

just adds a whole new line at the bottom, while the function:

```
_FileWriteToLine($LOG, 1, "FText", 0)
```

adds the the letters `FText` to the beginning of the first line in the log file.

Is there any way I can add this text to the end of the first line, instead of the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

```
$TEXT = FileRead($LOG)  
_FileWriteToLine($LOG, 1, $TEXT & "FText", 1)
```

Courtesy of boththose, he answered this question [here](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/162559-append-a-string-of-text-to-the-end-of-a-line/?view=getnewpost)